# symfony not compatible with php version 7

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I am facing problem in configuring symfony 2.3.6 in php version 7 server. Please help me to solve the issue or upgrading symfony to the latest.

Thank you

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: Upgrading Symfony is not a trivial task that can be easily explained in an answer. There are many, many things to consider + we know absolutely nothing about your app. I suggest you try creating a new project in the latest version and slowly start rewriting your old code to fit the new specs.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, **Symfony 2.3.6 is not longer maintained**, bug fixed nor security updated after May 2017. You must upgrade to newer version. It might be "[backward compatible](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/bc.html)" since Symfony 2.3.

As first step [upgrade](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/upgrade_minor.html) Symfony from 2.3 to 2.7. As second step [upgrade](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/upgrade_major.html) to Symfony 3. As next step to Symfony 4. As last step upgrade to Symfony 5.

[image: Symfony 2.3 lifecycle]